# Scikit-learn and weka randomforest regressor gives different results

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, weka, random-forest

I am using sciki-learn RandomForestRegressor for a regression problem with parameters

> random_state=1,
>   n_estimators=100,max_features='log2',min_impurity_decrease=1e-3

similarly I used weka randomforest for the same regression problem with the following parameters

> BagsizePercent=100, maxDepth = 0,  numFeatures = 0, numIterations=100,
>   seed =1

As I understand, n_estimators = numIterations, random_state = seed and other weka parameter values are the same as the default scikit-learn values.

But I get inferior results  with scikit-learn (very inferior to weka).  When I set the `max_features = 'auto'` which corresponds to `numFeatures = 0`, my results gets worse.

I thought, the degradation might be because of the random split for testing.  So I modified those as follows,
in weka, i chose

> percentage split = 50%

and set

> Random seed for XVal/%Split = 1
>   and 
>   unchecked the Preserve Order for % split

(With a checked Preserve Order for %split, I get far better result with Weka).

Similarly, in my scikit-learn code,  I set

> train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.5, random_state=1, shuffle=False);

But still my results are very bad.

What can be wrong ?

Comment: Just to clarify one thing, when you're doing `max_features = 'auto'` it is not the same as doing `numFeatures = 0`. By setting `max_features` to `auto` it would mean: `sqrt(n_features)`. Similar to setting it up to `sqrt`.

Comment: I think you are wrong according to the docs. there is sqrt as another option.  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html

Comment: you are right, it was my mistake, I thought we are talking about RandomForestClassifier not Regressor, sorry.

Comment: Please try to split the dataset manually into 50% training and 50% testing data. I have doubts that the seed works the same for weka and scikit. If you don't have much data, the different ways the train/test split is performed might influence your result to a significant amount